# How I can make the following work for functions members of a class?

Tags: c++

The following is a timer.

```
template <typename Duration, typename Function>
void timer(Duration const & d, Function const & f)
{
    std::thread([d,f](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(d);
        f();//error here
    }).detach();
}
```

Sample `myclass` definition is

```
class myclass {
public:
    void my_functions() const {
        std::cout << "my_functions called";
    }
};
```

And I call it like this:

```
timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(10), &myclass::my_functions());
```

When I try to call it on a member function I get `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

Comment: is it a static member function? Otherwise, how would the system know on which object to call it?

Comment: Is this the real code? What does `myclass::my_functions()` return? Are you trying to get a function pointer to a member? Is it static?

Comment: @Aganju No it's not a static

Comment: @MATH000 you can't reference non-static members just like that

Comment: @buld0zzr my_functions() display a message and returns void.

Comment: if it is not `static`, it needs an object to be called on, so this cannot work.

Comment: @Aganju Can you please help me call it the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

To pass a non-static member function to another function you need to utilize `std::function` and `std::bind` from [functional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header, as well as instantiate the object

```
myclass mc;
timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(1), std::bind(&myclass::my_functions, mc));
```

However, your code might not work as expected, because to see the message you must wait for the thread to make a call. Here's a simple example of a working one

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

template <typename Duration, typename Function>
void timer(Duration const & d, Function const & f)
{
    std::thread([d, f](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(d);
        f();//error here
    }).detach();
}

class myclass{
public:
    void my_functions() const {
        std::cout << "aaa";
    }
};

int main(){
    myclass mc;
    timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(1), std::bind(&myclass::my_functions, mc));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
}
```

The proper way would be of course to wait for thread completion.

Also, if the sole purpose of your member function is to output a message, you can make it static and do without binding.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is a non static member function is not the same as a regular or static function. It has a hidden parameter that it takes and that is pointer to the object the function is being called on.

You have a couple ways to fix this.  First you can make it static and then it treats it just like a normal function whose name is scopeed to the class.  If you cannot do that then you can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to create function like object that you can call the function operator on.  It would be used like

```
timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(10), std::bind(&class_name::my_functions(), &class_instance));
```

Lastly you could use a lambda to wrap the call just like `bind` does.  For that the syntax would be

```
timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(10), [&class_instance](){
    return class_instance.my_functions(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call non-static methods/functions without an object instance (even if the object is not really needed inside the method/function).

To achieve a method call without the need for an object, declare that method `static` (can still be inside the class, but add `static` before its name).

Comment: what about `std::function` and `std::bind`? Your answer is not complete

Comment: From what the OP writes and wants to do, the function really _is_ static, so it doesn't make sense to have it non-static and then bind it. This is the easiest solution, and the other two are technical work-arounds that would show little understanding of OO concepts. Therefore, I did not list them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay to charge argument list of your `timer()` function then this will also works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

template <typename Duration, typename Function, typename Class>
void timer(Duration const & d, Function const & f,Class const& o)
{
    std::thread([d,f,o](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(d);
        f(o);//error here
    }).detach();
}
class Foo{
public:
    Foo() {}
    void func() const {
        std::cout<<__func__<<":"<<__LINE__<<std::endl;};
    }

int main(){
    std::function<void(const Foo&)> foo_func = &Foo::func;
    const Foo foo;
    timer(std::chrono::seconds(2),foo_func,foo);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    return 0;
}
```